# FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. in flutter gradle

Tags: flutter, gradle, groovy, build, sdk

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':gradle:compileGroovy'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':gradle:detachedConfiguration1'.
> Could not find org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:?.?.??.
> Searched in the following locations:
> - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy/?.?.??/groovy-?.?.??.pom
> - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy/?.?.??/groovy-?.?.??.pom
> Required by:
> project :gradle
> Could not find org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-ant:?.?.??.
> Searched in the following locations:
> - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy-ant/?.?.??/groovy-ant-?.?.??.pom
> - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy-ant/?.?.??/groovy-ant-?.?.??.pom

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 10s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
The Flutter CLI developer tool uses Google Analytics to report usage and diagnostic
data along with package dependencies, and crash reporting to send basic crash
reports. This data is used to help improve the Dart platform, Flutter framework,
and related tools.

Telemetry is not sent on the very first run. To disable reporting of telemetry,
run this terminal command:

```
flutter --disable-analytics
```

If you opt out of telemetry, an opt-out event will be sent, and then no further
information will be sent. This data is collected in accordance with the Google
Privacy Policy (https://policies.google.com/privacy).

Please note that analytics reporting was already disabled, and will continue to be disabled.

I Tried to change "Gradle" and and setup tha android studio but no solution

Comment: Stackoverflow has many of this question